# Adding href to anchor using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list, href

I created a menu bar and created dynamically the li and anchor using js.
Now can I add the href and text usng JavaScript to each of the created list:
`<li><a></li></a>`
`<li><a></li></a>..`
so when clicking on any of the list items, it moves to the linked section on the page.

Comment: Yes it is possible. But to try, It would be great if you can share us what you have tried (your code snippet) ?

Comment: for example:   li.setAttribute('href',"    ")
                        li.innerText = "   ";                                                                                    but it is not working to link to  li maybe to use with img

Comment: Hi @bcodeu! Welcome to SO! If you could please include your javascript and your HTML document, other users will be able to help you troubleshoot and provide more insightful answers. :)

Comment: Hi thanks I found the answer from the below responds. My next participations I will try to post code snippet :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select and iterate over your `li>a`s and set their `href` and any other attribute you want. Something like below

```js
const links = [{
  title: 'Google',
  link: 'google.com'
}, {
  title: 'Yahoo',
  link: 'yahoo.com'
}, ];

document.querySelectorAll('li>a').forEach((itm, index) => {
  if (index >= links.length) return;
  itm.href = links[index].link;
  itm.text = links[index].title
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a />
  </li>
  <li>
    <a />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or you can add `li`s dynamically according to your array of links.

```js
const links = [{
  title: 'Google',
  link: 'google.com'
}, {
  title: 'Yahoo',
  link: 'yahoo.com'
}, ];

let ul = document.getElementById('nav');

links.forEach(itm => {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = itm.link;
  link.text = itm.title
  li.appendChild(link)
  ul.appendChild(li)
})
```

```html
<ul id="nav"></ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to give every item a unique id.
Then use their id as a reference and add their href attribute.

Let's consider your element is

```
<li><a id='list1'>Stackoverflow</a></li>
```

And the js code will be

```
<script>
      document.getElementById("list1").href = "https://stackoverflow.com"; 
</script>
```